# Edit app.iml in Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, junit, robolectric

After 3 days struggling to make JUnit and Robolectric to work with Android Studio I finall did it, but there is one important step I have to make everytime I open the IDE.

I have to go to app.iml and change "false" to "true" in "ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION". After this the testing works, but it's really annoying to make this change everytime I open the IDE.

Is there anyway to keep this change saved? I've looked for this option in the UI but I couldn't find nothing similar.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be an issue, but should no longer be a problem with the new Android Studio [support for unit tests](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support).

Checkout the instruction and setup in this sample project: https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've tried that option and it was the first one. Now I reverted the configuration I made with robolectric and did exactly step by step the instruciones from that site and it worked like a charm. I feel so bad after trying like 3 days doing this... But well... it's part of the learning. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Thanks Eric. You can accept the answer, if it solved your problem. You need at least 15rep to upvote.